# aws elastic beanstalk; how to move a file within my app root using .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to move a file located within my app directory:

```
{MyAppRoot}/.aws_scripts/eb_config.js
```

to

```
{MyAppRoot}/config.js.
```

I need this mv or cp to happen before the app is actually restarted, as this files presence is required immediately by the main app module. I've tried using .ebextensions various mechanisms like commands, container_commands, etc but all fail, with either no stat, or permission denied. I'm unable to get further details from eb_activity.log or any of the other log files. I came across this [similar question on the aws forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=752635) but I'm not able to achieve any success.

What's the proper way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `commands`your project specific files are not set up yet.

In `container_commands` they files are in a temporary staging location, but current path is that staging directory. The following should work:

```
container_commands:
    cp .aws_scripts/eb_config.js config.js.
```

Comment: thanks. I ended up doing it in container_commands, although I swear it was failing there as well on previous attempts, but working now.